# SQL sum of inhabitants

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

```
ID  ---- Sum  
w01D    2812202  
w02D    3353163  
w03C    2443837  
w04D    1975115  
w05A    4664729  
...     ...
```

In column 'ID' , w01,w02,... is an identificator of a state , and letters A,B,C,D points at region, where given state is located. 
In column 'Sum' there is a number of inhabitants living in each state.
Of course the whole table is much longer.

My goal is to display the sum of inhabitants in regions A,B,C,D and i dont know how to do it.
Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Is the region identifier always 1 letter at the end? Are these the only 4 regions?

Comment: To improve the Quality of your Question, please refer to the research that you have performed into this matter, with particular mention being made of any sources that proved to be particularly useful.  Please show us what code you have used (if any) along with the full text of any error messages it produces.  Please show us a table (based on the sample data) as text in the Question that shows us how the results should appear.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask a Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group by` using the `RIGHT()` function like below [This will work only if the identifier A,B,C,... is 1 character at the right]

```
select right(ID, 1) as Identifier, sum([Sum]) as Total_Population
from inhabitate
group by right(ID, 1);
```

Comment: But D ends both w01D and w02D. Which ID is selected?

Comment: @jarlh, yes got it ... so removed my earlier comment

Comment: Thank you very much, that resolver my problem, i just didnt know about existence of right and left functions, im fairly new to sql :)

Comment: @Bonjo, then accept the answer by clicking the check button